# Generating barcode and text under barcode

Tags: java, android

I want to generate `barcode` and text under this `barcode` , Now I only generate a `barocode` and I do not have a text under a `barcode` I do this :

```
String text="12345678";
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
try {
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.EAN_8,250,250);
    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Log.d("barcode", "barcode");
} catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to get this :

[image]

Comment: Why you want to generate text?

Comment: @Awadesh I want to print this barcode and text

Answer (score 0):

I would try this with the BarcodeEAN Class, where you can set your barcode also under your image. You can get some more Info about it http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.10/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeEAN.html.

Comment: It is a free for comerrcial use ?

Comment: As i know, it's free yes

Comment: Ok I try generate barcode from this but it does not work

Comment: If you want to stay with zxing lib, then the easiest way to get your String under your Barcode is an EditText, setted with the String. If you want to try with itextpdf, pls send what went wrong :)